# JMeter - How to execute just one thread group every 30 seconds within 60 seconds test

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have a JMeter Test Plan composed by 2 thread groups that runs consecutively:

Thread Group 1: [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuOtz.png)

- Login transaction (gets user token saved as property)

Thread Group 2: API requests [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG7FQ.png)

- Transaction 1
- Transaction 2
- ...

I want to execute **Thread Group 1 (get user token) every 30 seconds within 60 seconds** (2 times each global execution).

Do you know how to do it?

If I use a constant timer in Thread Group 1, it waits 30 seconds to start the thread and I don't want that behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter Timers are executed **before** each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in their [Scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so you have the following options:

1. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the `logintokensso` request and configure it to "sleep" for 30 seconds:

   [image]
2. Or if you have to use the timer for any reason you can still go for the Flow Control Action sampler but with zero delay and make your Constant Timer a child of this Flow Control Action sampler:

   [image]

Comment: When I add a Flow Control to the login transaction, Thread group 2 never starts.

Do you know how to configure it in order to start the second thread group after the first login? 

The second login should start after 30 seconds while the thread group 2 is running.

Thanks and regards